# Javascript proxy pattern with global objects as arguments

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I've developed a javascript app called "MyAPP", which makes use of proxy pattern, but adding some global objects passed through as local variables. As far as I know, this should slightly quickens the resolution process and can be more efficiently minified (especially when both are regularly referenced).

What do you think about that? Here is the pattern:

```
;(function() {

  "use strict";

  // Cached global objects
  var w = arguments[ 0 ], // window
      $ = arguments[ 1 ], // jQuery
      undefined;          // prevent undefined to be override

  // Local vars
  var lorem = 1,
      ipsum = [],
      dolor = {};

  /**
   * PRIVATE METHODS
   * =======================================================================
   */

  function methodOne () {

  }

  function methodTwo () {

  }

  /**
   * PUBLIC METHODS
   * =======================================================================
   */

  // MyAPP.UI.Tooltip.publicMethod01();
  this.publicMethod01 = function ( ){

  };

  // MyAPP.UI.Tooltip.publicMethod01();
  this.publicMethod02 = function ( ){

  };

}).apply( MyAPP.UI.Tooltip, [ window, jQuery ]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question should probably have been asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You know that you can't override undefined anymore ? You can shadow it, of course, but you shouldn't care and you don't prevent it.

Comment: It looks like you write a lot of code to prevent problems you probably don't have.